# Namespace not found in visual studio 2013 project

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces

I am trying to check in some pending changes on visual studio 2013 to a team project, but the check in is continually rejected for the following reason:

The type or namespace name 'OpenQA' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This error occured after I deleted three files. Now, I can't build my project without this error appearing multiple times in relation to every file I have in source control.

I also have the error: CSC: Source file 'filename.cs' could not be found

Would anyone be able to give me some guidance on this? Particularly the first error, as I ahve never seen it before and I am quite stuck.

Thank you in advance

Comment: the namespace is probably in one of the files you deleted.

Comment: project is in vb.net or c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source file 'filename.cs' could not be found --> you, must be, deleted file without using project, right in source control. Open the project file in notepad, search for the file and delete XML related to that file

Namespace --> three things possible:

1. You deleted files that declare the namespace
2. You have a reference (in form of "using" or "imports") to namespace that doesn't contain any public members
3. You really remove the reference to the assembly that contains the namespace.

You can actually undelete/reverse your changes and start over, if that will make it easier